If $d_1,\cdots,d_k$ are all the positive divisors of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in increasing order, then $d_i d_{k+1-i}=n$ for all $i=1,\cdots,k$
I'm trying to proof that I can "pair" the divisors of a given natural number. If we pick $d_i$, by definition there exists $q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n=d_i q$, therefore $q$ is also a positive divisor of $n$ and then $q=d_j$ for some $j=1,\cdots,k$. I'd like to show that $j=k+1-i$. If not, then $j<k+1-i$ or $j>k+1-i$. In any case it follows that $n\neq d_{k+1-i}d_i$, so I need to prove that $d_{k+1-i}d_i=n=d_i d_j$, and proving this is equivalent to show that $d_{k+1-i}=d_j$, but I'm stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated.

As here pair up the factors using that the cofactor involution (reflection) $,d\to n/d,$ is order reversing. $\ \ $
